# snowflake throwing error while creating javascript stored proc returning a table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Quick question, I am getting an error calling a javascript function which returns a table. Can anyone point me to syntax errors?

**Error Message**:

---

> JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in MTRCS_NUM_TBL_FUNC at ' SELECT DISTINCT SESN_UUID,MTRCS_NM FROM MTRCS where MTRCS_NM = mTRCS_NM ' position 11

**Here is the code:**

```
create or replace function MTRCS_NUM_TBL_FUNC(mTRCS_NM VARCHAR(1000))
returns table (SESN_UUID VARCHAR(100) ,MTRCS_NM VARCHAR(1000))
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
as
$$ 
SELECT DISTINCT SESN_UUID,MTRCS_NM FROM MTRCS where MTRCS_NM = mTRCS_NM 
$$;
```

Comment: You cannot run SQL in a JavaScript UDTF. You can only run JavaScript. You also cannot use the `snowflake` object to run SQL because it's available only in JavaScript stored procedures not JavaScript UDTFs.

Comment: Can we return a resultset using SQL in JS Stored proc and then use the resultset to join with other tables?

Comment: No. JavaScript stored procedures cannot return tables. SQL Script SPs can return tables, but they still can't be used in a single statement in a join. You'd have to create a temp table using the JS stored procedure and join to that. Maybe there's another way to work around the collation issue. UTF-8 is default, so I'm not clear on the comment below about collating the table on it.

Comment: Good question. I have no idea why this client has setup collation with UTF-8 when it is the default. I am yet to find that.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is rather SQL UDTF and not JavaScript UDTF.

Second you should avoid the same name of the parameters and columns to avoid resolution errors or explicitly alias them:

```
create or replace table MTRCS(SESN_UUID VARCHAR(100) ,MTRCS_NM VARCHAR(1000))
AS
SELECT '1', '1' UNION ALL SELECT '2', '2';

create or replace function MTRCS_NUM_TBL_FUNC(_mTRCS_NM VARCHAR(1000)) 
returns table (SESN_UUID VARCHAR(100) ,MTRCS_NM VARCHAR(1000)) 
LANGUAGE SQL  -- <<< here
as 
$$ SELECT DISTINCT SESN_UUID,MTRCS_NM FROM MTRCS where MTRCS_NM = _mTRCS_NM 
$$;

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(MTRCS_NUM_TBL_FUNC('1'));
-- 1    1
```

---

Using the same parameter name as column name(as in original code):

```
create or replace function MTRCS_NUM_TBL_FUNC(mTRCS_NM VARCHAR(1000)) 
returns table (SESN_UUID VARCHAR(100) ,MTRCS_NM VARCHAR(1000)) 
LANGUAGE SQL  -- <<< here
as 
$$ SELECT DISTINCT SESN_UUID,MTRCS_NM FROM MTRCS where MTRCS_NM = mTRCS_NM 
$$;

SELECT *
FROM TABLE(MTRCS_NUM_TBL_FUNC('1'));
-- 1    1
-- 2    1
```

---

Third: If it was a JavaScipt function or stored procedure, then you should use uppercase parameters inside.

[Case-sensitivity in JavaScript Arguments](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript#case-sensitivity-in-javascript-arguments)

Comment: I am using "Javascript" UDTF because the columns on the table are set with "Collate UTF8" which cannot be used with SQL UDTF (Based on snowflake docs).

MTRCS_NM is set to "VARCHAR(1000) COLLATE 'utf8'"
SESN_UUID is set to "VARCHAR(100) COLLATE 'utf8'"